# Create ElasticTranscoder Job via Lambda with 2 Inputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-transcoder, aws-sdk-nodejs

I want to create an ElasticTranscoder Job via Lambda (NodeJS).

It works fine if I define one input (see below). But I have several source files. 
If I modify my coding, so that the input is an array, I'll get errors.

Can someone help me?

This works fine:

```
    transcoder.createJob({
    PipelineId: '12345678-vsyssc',
    Input: {
        Key: fileName,
        FrameRate: 'auto',
        Resolution: 'auto',
        AspectRatio: 'auto',
        Interlaced: 'auto',
        Container: 'auto'
    },
    Output: {
        Key: 'Output.mp4',
        ThumbnailPattern: '',
        PresetId: '1351620000001-000030',
        Rotate: 'auto'
    }
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong:', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Converting is done');
    }
    callback(err, data);
});
```

This doesnt work:

```
    transcoder.createJob({
    PipelineId: '12345678-vsyssc',
    Input: [{
        Key: 'VID-20180217-WA0002.mp4',
        FrameRate: 'auto',
        Resolution: 'auto',
        AspectRatio: 'auto',
        Interlaced: 'auto',
        Container: 'auto'
    }, {
        Key: 'VID-20180411-WA0012.mp4',
        FrameRate: 'auto',
        Resolution: 'auto',
        AspectRatio: 'auto',
        Interlaced: 'auto',
        Container: 'auto'
    },
    ],
    Output: {
        Key: 'test123445.mp4',
        ThumbnailPattern: '',
        PresetId: '1351620000001-000030',
        Rotate: 'auto'
    }
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong:', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Converting is done');
    }
    callback(err, data);
});
```

i get the Error:

> - UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '1' found in params.Input
>     at ParamValidator.validate (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:40:28)
>     at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:125:42)
>     at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:105:20)
>     at callNextListener (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:95:12)
>     at C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:85:9
>     at finish (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:315:7)
>     at C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:333:9
>     at SharedIniFileCredentials.get (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\credentials.js:126:7)
>     at getAsyncCredentials (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:327:24)
>     at Config.getCredentials (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:347:9)
>     message: 'There were 2 validation errors:\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key \'0\' found in params.Input\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key \'1\' found in params.Input',
>     code: 'MultipleValidationErrors',
>     errors: 
>     [ { UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '0' found in params.Input
>          at ParamValidator.fail (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:50:37)
>          at ParamValidator.validateStructure (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:77:14)
>          at ParamValidator.validateMember (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:88:21)
>          at ParamValidator.validateStructure (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:75:14)
>          at ParamValidator.validateMember (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:88:21)
>          at ParamValidator.validate (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:34:10)
>          at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:125:42)
>          at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:105:20)
>          at callNextListener (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:95:12)
>          at C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:85:9
>        message: 'Unexpected key \'0\' found in params.Input',
>        code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
>        time: 2018-06-10T11:39:59.749Z },
>      { UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '1' found in params.Input
>          at ParamValidator.fail (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:50:37)
>          at ParamValidator.validateStructure (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:77:14)
>          at ParamValidator.validateMember (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:88:21)
>          at ParamValidator.validateStructure (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:75:14)
>          at ParamValidator.validateMember (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:88:21)
>          at ParamValidator.validate (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:34:10)
>          at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:125:42)
>          at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:105:20)
>          at callNextListener (C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:95:12)
>          at C:\Users\Volkm\Google Drive\Quellcode\nodejs\ElasticTranscoderJob\test\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:85:9
>        message: 'Unexpected key \'1\' found in params.Input',
>        code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
>        time: 2018-06-10T11:39:59.749Z } ],
>     time: 2018-06-10T11:39:59.749Z }

Kind Regards
Stefan

Comment: Please show your attempt to transcode multiple files (using Inputs and Outputs) rather than one file (using Input and Output) and tell us what error you see.

Comment: @jarmod: I adjusted my question, hope someone can tell me whats the problem

Comment: The documentation indicates that you should pass (plural) Inputs and Outputs for multiple files, not (singular) Input and Output.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand your point. I try to provide multiple objects, but then it doesn't work.how should i pass multiple objects in an other way as i tried?

Comment: sorry, now i got it. You are right. if i use the "Inputs"-Property instead of "Input" it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it's working. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [createJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticTranscoder.html#createJob-property) operation uses different properties for one file vs. multiple files.

For a single input/output file:

```
transcoder.createJob({
    PipelineId: '12345678-vsyssc',
    Input: { <input info> },
    Output: { <output info> },
});
```

For multiple input/output files:

```
transcoder.createJob({
    PipelineId: '12345678-vsyssc',
    Inputs: [ {<input #1 info>}, {<input #2 info>} ],
    Outputs: [ {<output #1 info}, {<output #2 info} ],
});
```

You use `Input` & `Output` (singular) in the former but `Inputs` & `Outputs` (plural) in the latter.

At a guess, the original `createJobs` method only supported a single file and was later enhanced to support multiple files. To avoid breaking backward compatibility AWS added `Inputs` & `Outputs`.